# PIP installing packages incorrectly or in the wrong location

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, cx-freeze

I've been following sentdex's python beginner series. I was doing well enough until I had to path python so I could use [pip](/questions/tagged/pip). I did that, and tried installing a few `whl` files, `cx_Freeze` and `PIL`.

It said everything was installed correctly and they're in `libs/site` packages but whenever I try to draw from them I get an error saying
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'` (or `PIL` or whatnot).

Am I getting the wrong version?

EDIT: So I thought the problem was that the python shell was in a different location than the rest of my python install, which is not the case, I just only saw part of the path. I re-ran the script in the command prompt version of python.exe and I got no errors. What the hell is going on

Comment: Maybe in your system two instances of python are installed.

Comment: Did you install the packages globally (with root access) or in a virtual environment? Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: I use 3.6. So I ran it with the command prompt python.exe and it ran, but when I try it with the shell it gives me the "module not found error."

Answer (score 1):

you probably run a different python or pip then the one you expect. It happens with me often. To avoid such an issue use:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
python -c "from PIL import Image; print(Image)"
```

by calling the same python executable you avoid problems using a pip that belongs to a different python install.

Comment: Where exactly do I run this? From the Python shell or the command prompt or Python.exe?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
python `which pip` install Pillow
```